# How to make join in rest api like in sql?

Tags: json, reactjs

I am currently new in programming especially in front end and I was wounder how to perform join in Json Restful API
I am using Json placeholder for my fake rest api

I have tried reading their document by I failed
https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/20
https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users

I want to join these two tables 
and display title,body from posts and username from user according to the userid in post

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you will have to either create an endpoint in your backend that would perform the read from two joint tables and return a DTO having all the fields that you require, or (if that's impossible) you will have to call both endpoints in your client. So for example you could fetch the users in one call, then retrieve posts in separate calls and write front-end logic to find the associated user and display the data you need.

Ex. call api to get users, store them in a users array in your front end client code, then call api to get post and search for the corresponding user in the user array by userId

Comment: This is helpful than you for your answer :)